# Deployment of ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Web App encounter can't currently handle this request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

As the title said, the error is

> sdemo-core.local can't currently handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

And the event log describe the error below from source IIS AspNetCore Module V2

> Could not load configuration. Exception message: Unable to get
> required configuration section 'system.webServer/aspNetCore'. Possible
> reason is web.config authoring error.

Pretty sure all the hosting bundle and package are installed but still encounter this error but can't find why from anywhere. Don't know wht it showing the web.config authoring error.

The code below is my web.config which published

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <configuration>   
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CountryWebAppMVC.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="240" hostingModel="inprocess"></aspNetCore>   
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Hope someone help if encounter this error before when publish ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Web APP by Folder option

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.